# Accept multiple styles in Firebug

Tags: firefox, firebug

For developing I use Chrome, but I have to fix one bug in Firefox. For quick tests I use Firebug, but it sucks at the custom style rules. For example, I have copied code like that:

```
width: 50px;height: 200px;color: red;
```

And after pasting it to Firebug, it will just remove me. Pasting this to Chrome's developers tools applies all styles perfectly.

What I can do is first to write `width` and then `50px`, etc. I can't do it like in Chrome. Is it a feature? Or why does it work like that? Because when I want to apply big style to test it, I don't want to write every style by one, it is slowing my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasting multiple CSS properties is currently (version 2.0.x) not possible in Firebug's [*Style* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Style_Side_Panel). This is filed as [issue 6902](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/6902).

The only possible way at the moment to add multiple styles at once is by adding a `style` attribute within the [*HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel) and paste the properties as value.

Though note that the Firefox DevTools can handle pasting multiple properties like the Chrome DevTools. And [Firebug 3 will be based on the Firefox DevTools](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2014/11/10/firebug-3-next-generation-of-firebug/), so it will inherit this feature.